# Printing content of pointer to struct member gives unexpected result

Tags: c

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct mytype {
  int x; int y; int z;
} mytype;
int main ()
{
  mytype* p = (mytype*)4;
  void* pp = &(p->x);
  printf("%d\n",(int)pp);

}
```

Prints "4" as expected.

But if I change the line:

```
void* pp = &(p->x);
```

To:

```
void* pp = &(p->y);
```

It prints "8". Also If I change it to p->z it prints "12".

Why is that?

Comment: Congratulations. You have redefined [`offsetof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) macro (with additional offset of 4).

Comment: I'm kind of curious, though. What result were you expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mytype* p = (mytype*)4;
```

declares a pointer to type `mytype` at address `0x04`.

```
void* pp = &(p->x);
printf("%d\n",(int)pp);
```

shows that the address of `mytype->x` is the same as the address of `mytype`.

Repeating for `p->y` and `p->z` show that `sizeof(int)==4` on your platform and the compiler has inserted no padding between the members of `mytype`

The offsets between `x`, `y` and `z` could change if you run the code on different platforms.

Note also that I think

```
printf("%d\n",(int)pp);
```

relies on undefined behaviour as there is no guarantee that `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(int)`

```
printf("%p\n",pp);
```

should be safer.

Answer (score 1):

You take your pointer, and you point it to the address of 4.  The first member of your struct (x), will reside here, so if you print the memory address of x, you're oging to get your intial starting place (4).  When you try and print y, it starts at 8 because its an int (and x  starts and 4 and goes to 8.)  Same with z (starts at 12, ends at 16, and y starts at 8, and ends at 12).

While there is no struct there, you're casting the memory there to your struct, so your pointer arithmetic will follow your structure's memory layout.